# Проблема с изменением высоты DIV

Tags: вёрстка, html, css

Доброго времени суток! Прошу помочь, я начинающий верстальщик,робую сверстать кое-что по своей задумке и у меня возникла следующая проблема:
Имею следующий код:

```
<body>
    <header></header>
    <div id="body">
    <div id="table-content-wrapper">
      <div id="cell-content-wrapper">
        <div id="main-page-content">
            <div style="height:20px; width:100%;"></div>
            <div style="height:139px; width:100%;"></div>
            <div style="max-height:70px; min-height:30px; height:10%; width:100%;"></div>
            <div style="height:211px; width:100%;"></div>
            <div style="max-height:30px; min-height:20px; height:5%; width:100%;"></div>
            <div style="height:100px; width:100%;"></div>
            <div style="max-height:45px; min-height:30px; height:7%; width:100%;"></div>
            <div style="height:61px; width:100%;"></div>
            <div style="height:20px; width:100%;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GZnEz/

Проблема: при изменении размеров окна, блоки имеющие атрибуты min-max height не меняют своей высоты, точнее меняют, но сразу, РЕЗКО, в предельные значения то-есть было допустим 30 становится резко 70px, плюс ко всем 'резкое' изменение высот происходит только когда элементы 'наслоятся' на footer на 61px! Помогите сделать чтобы элементы main-page-content не выходили за границы блока и происходило плавное изменение высот подобных блоков.

```
<div style="max-height:70px; min-height:30px; height:10%; width:100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Для начала избавьтесь от инлайновых стилей и вынесите все оформление в CSS.

Comment: Спасибо за коммент, я это для тестов сделал, так-то всё в css находится, но работает одинаково=(

Comment: у меня глаза кровью наливаются, когда я пытаюсь в такой постановке разобраться. Почему бы вам не скопировать стили из "не тестов"?